# What happens to the future that has been spawned off by my actor that restarts

Tags: scala, akka, future

I have an Akka Actor(ARCWorker) that has a one-to-one supervisor strategy to restart upon any exception.

```
def idle: Receive = {
    case UnitOfWork(data, service) =>
      {
        data.HelperRef = Some(ftpHelper)
        val futurework = service(data)
        futurework pipeTo self
        context.become(busy)
      }
}
```

This futurework take some time to complete. My ARCWorker watches the master and if the master dies it restarts itself and goes to un-initialized state. At that point I don't want my ARCWorker to receive the result of the futurework.

So my questions:
1) What happens to my futurework if I throw an exception and let supervisor take care of restarting ARCWorker?
2) What happens if I do a context.stop of the ARCWorker? ( I think supervisor won't deal with but want to confirm)
3) Is there a way to cancel my futurework in case no other option is available to me?

Thanks
    Manas

Comment: You do not need and should not include the braces around the expressions to the right of the `=>` in a case clause.

Answer (score 1):

A `Future` created by an actor is unaffected by the subsequent restart or death of the actor whose receive function created it.

Comment: Will the recreated actor receive the result of the future?

Comment: If and when the actor is restarted, yes that "piped-to" result will be received by the restarted actor whose earlier incarnation started the future. (I have to assume that `service(data)` does in fact return a `Future[T]` and that you have the implicit in scope that makes a `Future[Something]` into a `PipeableFuture[T]` ... or that `service(date)` returns a `PipeableFuture[T]` directly.)

Comment: Yes Randall. My service(data) is a future. Does Scala or Akka provide any other Monad that I can use to work my payload async and be able to cancel when I find it necessary? If I may give some more info about the ARCWorker: It's master provides work with a Deadline. When the deadline is met the work should be unloaded and quarantined. The idea is to keep the CPU busy with necessary work and if a work hangs(takes more than configured amount of time) should be off-loaded.

Comment: Yes. Look for the `Future.firstCompletedOf` method (that's in `object Future`, not `trait Future`) which takes several `Future`s (technically, a `TraversableOnce[Future]`) and returns the first one that completes.

Comment: When a computation hangs on the JVM, there is no way to kill it from the outside, which means that your service will need to check periodically for some cancelation signal if you want to interrupt it.